# Laravel 5 javascript caching error, works fine when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2, and Bootstrap 3 admin template
I have two links on my navigation menu: Home and About
When I am on Home, and click on About, it goes to the about page, but the javascript does not load. However, when I click on refresh or even on the About link, it works fine. 
It's the same with the Home page: if I click on the Home link or hit refresh while I'm on the home page, it works fine. But then if I click on the Home page while I am on the About page, the javascript on the Home page does not load until I hit refresh or click on Home link. 
My routes are set up in the simplest form, see routes.php below:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'AboutController@index');
```

The controllers were made with artisan and are like:

```
    class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

The scripts are inside of the app.blade.php layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Website - @yield('title')</title>

    <link href="/css/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        /* yeah we need this empty stylesheet here. It's cool chrome & chromium fix
         chrome fix https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167083
         https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332189
         */
    </script>

</head>

<body id="app-layout">

    @include('layouts.navigation')
    <div class="wrap">
        @include('layouts.header')
        @include('layouts.contentcontainer')
        @include('layouts.loader')
    </div>

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-pjax/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/widgster/widgster.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/settings.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery.sparkline/index.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.js"></script>


    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/chat.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @GauravDave added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

The scripts were being included twice mistakenly. Once in the app.blade.php, and then in the actual home.blade.php and about.blade.php. 
Instead, I made them load once, and now the problem is solved.